# MongoDb c# driver consecutive SelectMany

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

If I have objects, lets call them **Group** that has list of some other objects I will call it **Brand**, and this object has a list of objects called **Model**.

Is there a way to get only list of **Models** using MongoDb c# driver.

I tried using *SelectMany* multiple times but with no success. If I put more than one *SelectMany* I always get an empty list.

Code should be self-explanatory.
At the end is comment that explains what confuses me.

```
class Group
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(GuidGenerator))]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
}

class Brand
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Model> Models { get; set; }
}

class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Produced { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:32768");
        var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<Group>("groups");

        var fca = new Group { Name = "FCA" };

        var alfaRomeo = new Brand { Name = "Alfra Romeo" };
        var jeep = new Brand { Name = "Jeep" };
        var ferrari = new Brand { Name = "Ferrari"};

        var laFerrari = new Model { Name = "LaFerrari", Produced = 4 };

        var wrangler = new Model { Name = "Wrangler", Produced = 3 };
        var compass = new Model { Name = "Compass", Produced = 8 };

        var giulietta = new Model { Name = "Giulietta", Produced = 7 };
        var giulia = new Model { Name = "Giulia", Produced = 8 };
        var _4c = new Model { Name = "4C", Produced = 6 };        

        fca.Brands = new List<Brand> { ferrari, alfaRomeo, jeep };

        ferrari.Models = new List<Model> { laFerrari };
        jeep.Models = new List<Model> { wrangler, compass };
        alfaRomeo.Models = new List<Model> { giulietta, giulia, _4c };

        collection.InsertOne(fca);                 

        Console.WriteLine("press enter to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();

        var models = collection.AsQueryable().SelectMany(g => g.Brands).SelectMany(b => b.Models).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(models.Count);    //returns 0 I expected 6
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: SelectMany seems ok in your code. did data save into DB?  Try var models = collection.AsQueryable().SelectMany(g => g.Brands).ToList().SelectMany(b => b.Models).ToList();

Comment: @Mate data is saved into DB. Your code works, however I would like to not use it like that. Because in that case second SelectMany do job on C# virtual machine not in database engine as it should and also use more traffic

Comment: ok I understand, check your c# driver version and read about **MongoQueryable.SelectMany**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
var models = collection.AsQueryable()
 .SelectMany(g => g.Brands)
 .Select(y => y.Models)
 .SelectMany(x=> x);

Console.WriteLine(models.Count());
```

Working output (with extra Select())

```
aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$Brands"
}, {
    "$project": {
        "Brands": "$Brands",
        "_id": 0
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "Models": "$Brands.Models",
        "_id": 0
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$Models"
}, {
    "$project": {
        "Models": "$Models",
        "_id": 0
    }
}])
```

OP Output without extra Select()

```
 aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$Brands"
}, {
    "$project": {
        "Brands": "$Brands",
        "_id": 0
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$Models"
}, {
    "$project": {
        "Models": "$Models",
        "_id": 0
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Could you please explain in more details why it is necessary to use Select in between two SelectMany? This is definitely a different behavior than in System.Linq.

Comment: @topolm Great!  Honestly, I don't know why. I've working with the "most popular" ORMs and all of them have some problem with SelectMany() translation. 
Usually the solution is the same, verify the output query. 
Anyway I'll try to learn more about this.
Please, check the update. It's clear there